# How to remove old style URLs from the Google Index completely and replace them with a new style?

Tags: google-search-console, url, google-index

I had previously submitted my sitemap to Google. The structure of the URLs in it is `https://example.com/username`
The username there is a URL slug generated based on the user's name.   There is also another URL associated with each user `https://example.com/username/branches`.  Google also indexed it.

I recently changed my whole website design and URL structure.
The first URL `https://example.com/username` is same but  `https://example.com/username/andOtherUrlsAppendedtothis` is new URL that we designed to replace the second.

Also I have almost 56,000 URLs that follows the old URL structure.
How can I remove those URLs from Google index?

Comment: Which URL you want to remove and replace? `domain.com/username` or `domain.com/username/branches` ? The question is not clear to me. Sorry. You said the first url structure is same, so I think `domain.com/username` is not changed, and you want to replace second URL stricture like `domain.com/username/branch` to something else. Right? And one important question, is content change when you replace branch URL to something else URL. or you just have change URL structure and have similar content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to replace:

https://example.com/username/branches with https://example.com/username/andOtherUrlsAppendedtothis

Then all you need to do is set a permanent 301 redirect. Considering you got a high volume of URLs, i would recommend you to handle using the code and make sure the HTTP response is 301.

Once you do this, you will see in few weeks most of the old URL will get changed to the new one.

Comment: Or simply wait. This is how the web works. It just requires patience which seems to be in shorter supply these days.

Comment: Don't simply wait without setting up 301s, unless you want to lose all links to those old URLs.

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to replace then simply use 301 Redirection. And after some week you will get the new result in google search Result.

if you don't want to do 301 redirection then add the no follow no index tag in that page.and submit the sitemap to google.

One other solution is that block that page through robots.txt and also temporary hide through google webmaster and after some time that page is removed by google.